# Why can't a property with type IList implements a property with type IEnumerable in interface?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

In C#, IList inherit from IEnumerable. Then why would the following code show compile-time error?

```
public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    public IList<string> Words { get ; set ; } // compile-time error; must use IEnumerable as type here
}

public interface MyInterface
{
    IEnumerable<string> Words { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Short answer is, C# doesn't support return type covariance so that would not work. If you're going to override a member of an interface/class in a derived class, the signature must match. In this case, your `Words` property must explicitly return an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: However since this is an interface, as an alternative, you could explicitly implement the member which just forwards to your actual property.

Comment: On the other hand, since you have also made the property settable, that would only further complicate things and would break everything. What would happen if you had a reference to your class through that interface and you set a non-list ienumerable?